# Partial short circuit boolean evaluation in Javascript or C#

Tags: c#, javascript, boolean, evaluation

Is there a way, in JavaScript or C#, to determine the outcome of a logical expression before the 
values of all variables have been retrieved?

Or to put it differently; can an expression be evaluated such that it returns either 'true', 'false', or 'maybe'? Wherein 'maybe' indicates that more data is needed.

To explain: I have a process in which it takes some time to retrieve data from the database backend and I would like to see if we can skip retrieving certain data if not necessary. But the logical expressions have been predetermined and can not be changed or taken apart.

For instance, consider the following expression:

```
((a = 1) and (b = 2)) or (c = 3)
```

There are several possibilities:
If `a` and `b` have been retrieved but `c` has not yet been retrieved:

- If `a=1` and `b=2` then the expression will always return true and I can skip retrieving the value for `c`
- If `a=0` and `b=2` then the first part will be false, and I need to retrieve the value for `c` in order to being able to determine the outcome

If `c` has been retrieved, but and `a` and `b` have not yet been retrieved.

- If `c=3` then the expression will always return true and I can skip retrieving the value for `a` and `b`.
- If `c=2` then the first part will be false, and I need to retrieve the value for `a` and `b` in order to being able to determine the outcome

In these situations, just knowing that an outcome is already determined, or that more data is needed can significantly speed up a process.

Does anybody have an idea? A process, function, algorithm?

Comment: normally all of these shortcuts add up in iterations to save total task time, not sure how you would optimize it more in terms of total time. you can make it more responsive by running two passes: one to compute if c is needed on all, and the 2nd to fetch further details for the transactions that need it.

Comment: Do you have a data structure representing these expressions? Then you can write a simple interpreter that treats gives true/false/unknown as result, with "unknown" representing that more data is needed (e.g. `c = 3` is true if c = 3, false if c = 2, and unknown if c has not yet been retrieved). "Unknown" would propagate appropriately through the boolean operators.

Answer (score 0):

So to cover your very specific code, you can simply use the following:

```
if(CHasValue())
    return (c == 3) or ((a == 1) and (b == 2))
else
    return ((a == 1) and (b == 2)) or (c == 3)
```

short circuiting of operators will take care of the rest.

This doesn't scale very well with more complex expressions though.  In order to really cover any arbitrary boolean expression you really need to create your own new type, and corresponding boolean operators.

We'll start out with an interface defining a boolean value that may or may not have computed its value yet:

```
public interface IComputableBoolean
{
    public bool Value { get; }
    public bool ValueComputed { get; }
}
```

The first implementation is the easy one; it's a computable boolean representing a value that we already know:

```
public class ComputedBoolean : IComputableBoolean
{
    public ComputedBoolean(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public bool Value { get; private set; }
    public bool ValueComputed { get { return true; } }
}
```

Then there's the slightly more complex case, the boolean value that is generated based on a function (presumably something that is potentially long running, or that has side effects).  It will take a delegate that computes the expression, evaluate it the first time the value is requested, and return a cached value (and indicate that it has computed its value) from then on.

```
public class DeferredBoolean : IComputableBoolean
{
    private Func<bool> generator;
    private bool? value = null;
    public DeferredBoolean(Func<bool> generator)
    {
        this.generator = generator;
    }
    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (value != null)
                return value.Value;
            else
            {
                value = generator();
                return value.Value;
            }

        }
    }
    public bool ValueComputed { get { return value != null; } }
}
```

Now we just need to create `And`, `Or`, and `Not` methods that apply to this interface.  They should first check to see if enough values are computed to allow it to short circuit, and if not, they should create a deferred boolean representing the computation of the value.  This propagation of deferred values is important, because it allows complex boolean expressions to be composed and still properly short circuit with the minimal amount of needed computation.

```
public static IComputableBoolean And(
    this IComputableBoolean first,
    IComputableBoolean second)
{
    if (first.ValueComputed && !first.Value ||
        second.ValueComputed && !second.Value)
        return new ComputedBoolean(false);
    else
        return new DeferredBoolean(() => first.Value && second.Value);
}

public static IComputableBoolean Or(
    this IComputableBoolean first,
    IComputableBoolean second)
{
    if (first.ValueComputed && first.Value ||
        second.ValueComputed && second.Value)
        return new ComputedBoolean(true);
    else
        return new DeferredBoolean(() => first.Value && second.Value);
}
```

The `Not` operation is a bit different in that it can't short circuit at all, but it's still important to have in that it continues to defer evaluation of the given boolean expression, because it may end up not being needed.

```
public static IComputableBoolean Not(
    this IComputableBoolean boolean)
{
    if (boolean.ValueComputed)
        return new ComputedBoolean(boolean.Value);
    else
        return new DeferredBoolean(() => boolean.Value);
}
```

We can now represent the expression that you have like so (using actual long running operations to compute `a`, `b`, and/or `c` as needed):

```
var a = new DeferredBoolean(() => false);
var b = new DeferredBoolean(() => true);
var c = new DeferredBoolean(() => false);

var expression = a.And(b).Or(c);
bool result = expression.Value;
```

Comment: this is definitely a valuable implementation of a boolean construct that can be used to defer lengthy processes if unnecessary for the calculation of a condition.  The thoroughness of the solution, by extension, helps to answer the OP question of "Is there a way...?"

The short answer is "Yes there is, but it will take a lot of work, and you won't like it."  The shorter answer is "No there isn't, for most cases."

Answer (score -2):

Assuming a, b, c are truthy once they are loaded, and falsy beforehand (or perhaps a,b,c contain a "loaded" property you could check):

```
var isValid = false;
if (a && b) {
  if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
    isValid = true;
  }
}
if (!isValid && c) {
  if (c == 3) {
    isValid = true;
  }
}
```